# How I can develop an Android application under VisualBasic.Net in VisualStudio?

Tags: c#, android, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I would like to develop an **Android** application using **VB.Net** language under **VisualStudio**, for this task I heard about **[Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/visual-studio?_bt=44014803188&_bk=xamarin%20vb%20net&_bm=e&gclid=CJKWrfDu1cUCFTLLtAodrhUAbA)** framework for **VisualStudio**, but it only seems to install **Android** projects for **C#** language.

My needs as the needs of many other programmers are very simple, just as I said I would like to start developing an **Android** application using **VB.Net** language under **VisualStudio**, I hope is there an existing **Xamarin** workaround or another alternative to accomplish this task, because it is a global demand/requisite.

What can I do?, I'm not planning a transition to **C#** or moving to another *IDE* than **VisualStudio**.

Comment: I don't think it can do VB just yet.

Comment: You can write VB PCLs, but you can't write the application projects themselves in VB.NET. I think it's in the pipeline though.

Comment: Can't do it in .NET as the other answers say, but there is a Basic4Android (http://www.b4x.com/) that allows you to write Android code in Basic.

Comment: @Ron Beyer Thanks but Basic4Android is a Basic based IDE, is not VisualBasic.Net based, that IDE is the worst thing I've seen to develop, does not have any relevant feature such as code-completition, intellisense, a (detailed) debugger, a profiller, and the rest of features of VisualStudio, that's why my only requisite is to develop the app under VisualStudio because I speed-up my performance, I totally preffer to use Xamarin in C# under VisualStudio than that B4A joke. I appreciate your help and your software suggestion,I just express my personal opinion about that program. thanks for comment

Comment: Thats fine, I have no attachment to that company, but wishes and desires only go so far, the only other option you have right now is to appeal to Xamarin to hurry the hell up. Alternatively you may be able to get MonoGame to work with VB, http://community.monogame.net/t/monogame-template-vbnet-for-windows-desktop-directx/1213, but may not fit your situation.

Comment: Thanks again, I also don't have any "hate" to that company and if they improve their product is a good point, is just that when I compare an IDE to VisualStudio I always get the same conclusion, VisualStudio is incomparable (is the most complete IDE regardless of its supported languages), at least I could develop the class libraries in VB.Bet for xamarin usage as commented above. I think then my problem is half-solved, is beter than nothing!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think recently they added portable libraries for using VB.Net, you can have more information on the Xamarin Developer Guides (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/portable_visual_basic_net/)